# Not able to access query params passed to the REST api after adding the SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, rest, ssl-certificate

I genereated an ssl certificate for my REST api (used nodejs). After adding ssl to the REST api not able to  access the query parameters passed to the api

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: I built a frontend application where i am accessing some data from the backend. For example I hardcode the query params while using the api to request the data.                http://api.example.com/componentname/:id?param1=value1&param2=value                       This call will go to the backend. On the backend I am returning an error if params arent passed. Otherwise as usual i sent the success result. Everything worked fine till i was using http but once i added the ssl certificate to the url any params i pass through frontend goes as undefined on the backend.

Comment: http://api.example.com/componentname/:id?param1=value1&param2=value

Comment: this is just a dummy url i am sending bcz i can't share the actual url

Comment: Have you properly configured TLS termination? Also can you tell a bit more about your infrastructure. Are you deploying a single instance of this api on a server, or multiple. Because you can use NGINX in front of the nodejs api and terminate TLS there.

Comment: Can you elaborate about TLS termination. Yes deploying a single instance f this api on server

Comment: I contacted aws, the issue got resolved from their end. They will brief me about why the problem occured.